# Assets compiling failed in Laravel 5.4

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, npm

While compiling assets in laravel throws error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                      
error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /media/xxx/workspace/Projects/Laravel-blog/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-ia32-57/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 32-bit with Node.js 8.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 32-bit with Node.js 7.x
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  }
}
```

I think the problem is with environment binding as the error message shows.

And another thing to mention, if I compile only js file then its a successful build. And I tried `npm rebuild node-sass` but no help.
How can I fix the error?

Machine : Ubuntu 16.04
npm -v  : 5.5.1
node -v : v8.6.0

Answer (score 1):

The binding is searching for Node version 7 while you have version 8.

Try the following command:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: yea I tried that as well as `npm rebuild node-sass --force` and its not helping